# VB.NET: what does the 'friend' modifier do?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, oop, friend

What does the 'friend' modifier do in VB.NET?

Why is it the default modifier for GUI components in Visual Studio?

Comment: This reminds me of the quote, "C++: Where your friends can see your privates."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`friend` in VB.Net is the same as `internal` in C#, it means that it can be accessed anywhere in the same assembly, but not from other assemblies.

I think it's a sensible default since I would say that normally one assembly should not be using another assembly's GUI controls (unless it's a class library or similar that is built for the purpose).

Comment: I would go further and say that `Private` would be a better default modifier. Directly accessing another object's GUI controls is poor practise and will lead to tightly-coupled code that's hard to modify.

Comment: Well, I'm not disagreeing about best practices, but I assume it defaults to friend to make it easier for beginners to get started or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

Friend is available in VB:
The Friend (Visual Basic) keyword in the declaration statement specifies that the elements are accessible from within the same assembly,
From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/friend)

I believe the c# version is [internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)