# Where is the Friend access modifier intended to be used?

Tags: vb.net, friend, access-modifiers

The only place I've seen the Friend modifier used is in the WinForms designer, as alluded to in [Why is the modifier set to Friend in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707055/why-is-the-modifier-set-to-friend-in-winforms) and [VB.NET: what does the 'friend' modifier do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772815/vb-net-what-does-the-friend-modifier-do).

The Friend modifier appears to be an almost arbitrarily wide access level that was created to solve some historic architectural problem in VB, I just wonder if anyone has a meaningful continued use for it?

I have had some desires to expose methods only to a given namespace so as to roll the functionalities of a related collection of objects together and manage any of their non-thread-safe methods, while exposing the safe public methods to a wider scope in the same assembly. This access level does not exist yet Friend does. Possibly a corollary question then, is my usage of assemblies and namespaces at odds with what is intended?

In many cases it is not possible to separate functionality into different assemblies because of the strict hierarchy that assemblies have, which leads to having groups of related but separate objects that have access to each other's unsafe methods.

**Edit:**
While I know the function of the modifier, I am curious as to what practical purposes people have for it as I have not come across a situation where it would be the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is not a language problem but OOP dogma in general.

The `Friend` modifier might be confusing because it doesn't behave as it does in older languages such as C++. The reason why it doesn't behave the same way is because is not the same.

The [Friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx) modifier gives access to the declared object in an assembly scope, which means that any class within the assembly can access that object but it will still not be usable for code consuming your assembly. If it helps look also at C# [Internal Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As to why OOP goes against the C++ way of the Friend Modifier goes beyond my knowledge but perhaps [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-sharp-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword) might help.

Comment: Pedro thanks for that, the C++ definition is exactly the functionality I am looking for. I'm with you as to questioning why the .net languages would omit it.

Comment: I think it isn't .NET per se... May someone correct me if I'm wrong but nor Java nor any other OOP Language offers a functionality as the C++ Friend modifier. On the other hand it makes sense that all your assembly can access your Friend members, I mean, it's not like you should be going around distrusting yourself or your team.

Comment: If we want to discuss the differences in 'Friend' use between languages we should retag the question to include 'C++'. Not sure if that is what the OP really wants or just the 'Why' limited to the .Net universe.

Answer (score 7):

I use it in classes to prevent functions, methods or properties from being used *outside* of my assembly.

From inside an assembly, `Friend` and `Public` do the same thing, hence, it's *friendly* to the developer.  But if the class is used from an outside assembly, everything that is marked `Friend` won't be available, whereas `Public` will be.

The C# equivalent is `internal`.  The name `internal` probably gives a better definition than `Friend` of it's intended use.

Here is an arbitrary example.  I have a DLL that contains a bunch of custom controls that all need to draw certain images:

```
Friend Class ControlDraw

  Public Shared Sub DrawArrow(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal r as Rectangle, _
                              ByVal ad As ArrowDirection, ByVal ac As Color)

    //' Draw Special Arrow:

  End Sub

End Class
```

I can use this code throughout all of the controls in my project.  But when I publish the DLL and let others use it, the DrawArrow function is not available to the end user, just the controls from inside the project.

Why do this?

If it was `Public`, then I could never change the parameters without potentially breaking any consumers of the function.  But since it's my own method, I can add another parameter for BackColor or whatever, and update all of my controls that use it from within my own project.

I am basically saying, a `Friend` class or function is just for me to worry about, not the end user.  Once you make something `Public` to the outside world, you lose a little bit of control of it.

Also found this from an [Eric Lippert answer on using `Internal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016168/719186):

> The point of internal is not that it makes life difficult for Bob. It's that it allows you to control what expensive promises Project A is making about features, lifetime, compatibility, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Lars, though I'm well aware of what the modifier does, I am more interested in why it exists. Its scope appears arbitrarily wide and similar (i.e. namespace) scopes are not also included in the specification. In hindsight the title question might be slightly misleading my intent.

Comment: @JCollins Added an example.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: It is very useful when you have a commercial .dll. If you sell (for example) a bunch of controls you have built. Maybe there are classes or functions you want to have public but only for your need, maybe these function should not be called by others since there's the possibility to crash the system if it is not used correctly.